# displaying a resutset from database as individual numbers

Tags: php, arrays, string, implode

I am trying to display a set of values as comma separated.

my data is `$data = 123456789`
i want to display it as `(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)`

i tried doing `echo implode(',' ,(array)$data);`
But no result.

Comment: `implode(',' , str_split($data))`

Comment: No, still i get `123456789`

Comment: I can confirm that @splash58 's answer does produce `1,2,3,4,5...` etc. Can you perhaps show us more of your code that is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code

```
$data = 'value from database';
$data = (string)$data

$array = str_split($data);
print_r($array);
$string = implode(",",$array);
echo $string;
```

Here is Sample Output

```
 Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9
)
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

According to your code

```
$sc1 = mysqli_query($con, "select distinct pt from pl_pts where first<>'' AND date(dtime) = CURDATE() ORDER BY pt");

while ($sc2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sc1))
    {
    $data = (string)$sc2['pt'];
    $array = str_split($data);
    $string = implode(",", $array);
    echo "(".$string.")";//concated parenthesis
    }
```

Comment: actually i am fetching data from db and result set returns values and my query is
`$sc1 = mysqli_query($con, "select distinct pt from pl_pts where first<>'' AND date(dtime) = CURDATE() ORDER BY pt");
while($sc2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sc1)) {
$data = $sc2['pt'];
 $array = str_split($data);
print_r($array);
$string = implode(",",$array);
echo $string;
}`
not working

Comment: remove print_r() its for just display pupose

Comment: `$data =  $sc2['pt']; 
 $data = (string)$data;
 $array = str_split($data);
 //print_r( $array);
 $string = implode(",",$array);
echo $string;`, Again it displays `123456789`
But if i declare `$data = "123456789" manually, i get the result properly as `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`

Comment: edited code resulted like `()(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8)(9)`

Comment: what kind of data $sc2['pt'] contain ? can you attched the screen shot for you code and related data?

Comment: What you want exactly brother as you have shown desired output in your question and @bhupendra mistry exactly provide that now you are saying you want another form.

Comment: as this is not working see the previous comment  output like "()(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8)(9)" thats why i aked whta kind of data you have

Comment: sorry i had problem in data conversion. I changed it and it worked!